# Stretchable ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-fragments

I beg you not to downvote my question, because it can duplicate other questions, but i didn't find anything. 
I want to do Stretchable (or Resizable) ImageView. Attention to pictures: 
1. For example we have this layout (screen) 
[image]

2. My finger down to screen
[image]

3. My finger move to screen bottom. So ImageView zoom
[image]

4. My finger up to screen. ImageView size was returned with smooth animation
[image]

What name of this ImageView? Or how realize this? What do you think?

Comment: What you asked has nothing to do with **stretchability**. The image is fixed. There's just a ViewGroup which is slideable and partially covers the image.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein Why has nothing to do with stretchability? When you move finger, Image size changes and we have Stretchable effect

Comment: i think it is an parallex effect..

Comment: @krunalpatel parallex? what is it?

Comment: **1** - The word **stretchable** means that an image can be **anamorphically distorted** (stretched) to fit its container View. **2** - NO, the image doesn't change - it's alway there in full size (you don't see the **covered portion**). There's only a ViewGroup that scrolls OVER it. It would be an overkill, to re-**crop** the image dinamically (**to crop != to stretch**)

Comment: @FrankN.Stein agree with you. stretchable is unfortunate name

Answer (score 1):

this view is something like fading action bar :

```
https://github.com/ManuelPeinado/FadingActionBar
```

Comment: of course yes, you can see options from the sample demo

Answer (score 0):

whe you don't know which view is use than just use  Hierarchy Viewer

- Launch Your App  in emulator
- Launch the Hierarchy Viewer in eclipse

and debug your UI

[Source](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-ui.html)

Comment: Hierarchy Viewer? Why?

Comment: from that you can see view hierarchy that's why :)